# How to change default animation in Dialog component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) and I want to change the default animation when a Dialog is open so that when it opens up it appears from bottom to top.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the exact image what you plan? I cannot follow. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: No, there is no way to change the default animation (yet)

Comment: @prosti In the example (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog) when you click a button to open the dialog appears from top to bottom. I'd like to change that animation to be the oposite, bottom to top or however I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `transition` property.

```
 <Dialog
    transition={props => (
      <Slide direction="left" {...props} />
    )}
  >
  </Dialog>
```